# Moving multiple JQueryUI sliders in the DOM while keeping functionality & values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a page with a large number of JQueryUI sliders, in div `.origin`. Each slider has an associated checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, the slider should be moved- with all values intact- to div `.favourites`. If the checkbox is unchecked, the slider should be moved back to `.origin`.

### [Here's a JSFiddle of my attempts so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/zwQp4/1/)

Here's my function to detect the value of the checkbox and make DOM adjustments accordingly:

```
    $('[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var check = $(this),
            checked = $(check).prop("checked"),
            num = $(check).attr("id").split("-")[1],
            parent = $("#food-" + num),
            parentContent = $(parent).clone(),
            slider = "#" + $(parent).find('.slider').attr("id"),
            favelist = $(".favourites .content");
        alert(checked)
        //remove the original
        $(parent).remove();
        if (checked === true) {
            //add to favourites
            $(favelist).append(parentContent);        
        } else {
            //add to origin
            $(favelist).append(parentContent);        
        }
        //reinitialise slider
        loadSlider(slider)
     });
```

A number of things aren't working:

1) First and most significantly, after the slider and it's parent elements have been moved into the `.origin` div, clicks on the checkbox no longer register. The `alert(checked)` doesn't fire, and the `else` statement doesn't run. Why would a checkbox no longer register a click event after being moved in the DOM?

2) Secondly, the moved sliders have the correct value displayed on the highlight div, but the dragger-handles go back to the starting position. How can I re-initialise the slider with the dragger handle in the correct position?

--

### UPDATE- [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zwQp4/3/)

OK, first issue is resolved, thanks to the hint provided by Chad, below. I've rewritten the click event into two functions, so that the click event can be re-instantiated after the elements are re-created in the DOM:

```
    //Listen for checkbox to be checked
    function checkboxChecked() {
        $('[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            var checkbox = $(this);
            moveItem(checkbox); 
        });
    }

    //Create/Destroy items when clicked
    function moveItem(checkbox) {
        var check = $(checkbox),
            checked = $(check).prop("checked"),
            num = $(check).attr("id").split("-")[1],
            parent = $("#food-" + num),
            parentContent = $(parent).clone(),
            slider = "#" + $(parent).find('.slider').attr("id"),
            favelist = $(".favourites .content"),
            origin = $(".all .content");
            $(parent).remove();
        if (checked === true) {  
            $(favelist).append(parentContent);        
        } else {
            $(origin).append(parentContent);         
        }
       loadSlider(slider);
       checkboxChecked();    
    }

    //initialise checkbox move function 
    checkboxChecked();
```

Am still trying to solve the mystery of the handle positions being re-set to 0 despite the slider retaining it's value, as shown on the highlighter track.

Comment: As far as the first one, you're not actually moving it-- you're recreating it. Your binds have to be instantiated after the object itself exists, so you'd have to rebind each time that you recreated it.

Comment: Can you suggest how to rebind it in this case?

Comment: I've attempted to solve this by creating two separate functions, one to handle the click event and one to destroy&create the DOM elements. However, this triggers an infinite loop, as seen in my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwQp4/4/ - Can you suggest how I can re-write it to avoid this?

Comment: I don't think you really need to clone it. Why not just move it? http://jsfiddle.net/zwQp4/6/

Comment: For this version that works, thank you. I was cloning it because there will be a possible requirement to keep both copies in the final version, which introduces other issues re: IDs, labels & whether the inputs of both can be active at the same time, so for the simplicity of resolving these two issues I went with cloning & removing the original. But I appreciate your help, it's working much better than it was.